# How do I properly use shap decision plots and force plots with multiple regression targets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, shap

I have a Keras neural network with 26 features and 100 targets I want to explain with the [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) python library.
In order to plot the force plot, for instance, I do:

```
shap.force_plot(exp.expected_value[i], shap_values[j][k], x_val.columns)
```

Where:

- `exp.expected_values` is a list of size 100 with the base values for each of my targets (this is at least what I understand). The index `i` refers to the i-th target, I assume.
- `shap_values` refers to the Shapley values of all the features for each of the targets in each validation case. Therefore, `j` runs from 0 to 99 (i.e. the size of my targets) and `k` runs from 0 to the total number of validation cases.

What I find confusing is that `i` and `j` can actually be different and I do get a plot that looks OK. However, shouldn't they always be the same index? Shouldn't the i-th baseline target always be compared to the shap values of the i-th target?
Am I understanding the indices wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` should be the same, because you're plotting how `ith` target is affected by features, from base to predicted:

```
shap.force_plot(exp.expected_value[i], shap_values[i][k], x_val.columns)
```

where:

> - i stands for `ith` target class
> - k stands for `kth` sample to be explained.

The reason behind is `exp.expected_value` will be of shape `num_targets` and they will be base values for shap values to be added to, and shap values should be of shape `[num_classes, num_samples, num_features]`, if converted to numpy array.

So, e.g., to get shap values for kth datapoint in raw space, one would do:

```
shap_values[:,k,:].sum(1) + base_values
```

and for models using softmax to get to probability space one would do:

```
softmax(shap_values[:,k,:].sum(1) + base_values)
```

Note, this is assuming shap_values are of numpy array type.

Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: @jotNewie  Did it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers